# Working with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

```
$('form#register').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userAuth(this);
    // if done : do a
    // if fail : do b
});
$('form#login').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userAuth(this);
    // if done : do x
    // if fail : do y
});

function userAuth(form) {
    console.log( $(form).serialize() );
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(form).serialize()
    });
    request.done( function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
    });
}
```

How do I check done/fail in the submit handlers?

Yes, I do know that this requires basic understanding of `callback` and the `asynchronous` execution of javascript. I've read quite a few books and tutorials but I just don't seem to get it. So maybe an example here would help.

Comment: Please provide more information and a solid question.

Comment: I haven't quite understood your question. Do you want to pass callback functions for `userAuth`'s `done` and `fail`?

Comment: @Andre Yes, I want to do stuff **after** userAuth has completed, so yes callback functions for it I think. The concept is not clear to me yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to add callback parameters:

```
function userAuth(form, doneCallback, failCallback) {
    console.log( $(form).serialize() );
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(form).serialize()
    });
    request.done(doneCallback);
    request.fail(failCallback);
}
```

And call it as:

```
$('form#register').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userAuth(this, function(){
        //I'm done
    }, function(){
        //I failed
    });
});
```

Keep in mind that the callback functions will receive the same arguments as the `done` and `fail` from jQuery. If you don't want this, call them as:

```
request.done( function (msg) {
    doneCallback();
});
request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    failCallback();
});
```

Callback is not a difficult concept. Keep in mind that they're arguments like ints, strings, RegExps and so on. They're just happen to be a function, so they're callable.

**Edit to answer comment**

You can save a value from a function in more than one way:

```
var globalVariable;

userAuth(this, function() {
    var myValue = 4; // local variable

    globalVariable = myValue;

    window.explicitGlobalVariable = myValue; // same as above, except I haven't created a variable beforehand

    implicitGlobalVariable = myValue; // I'm omitting var keyword, so it will leak to global scope
})
```

The downside with this is that using global variables is a code smell in most cases. There are some ways to avoid them, but it would require more knowledge to what you need to achieve to give a good example.

Comment: I see, great! What if you want to save a value from a callback into a global variable defined outside the callback? Does it also have to be passed as a function?